# How to send a struct by ref containing a string from C# to unmanaged C++ library

Tags: c#, c, mono, unmanaged, managed

I need to send a struct from C# managed code to a C library.  The C library will populate the values in the struct.  I have been trying to pass the struct as a reference so that the C# code will get the updated data values.

This is an example C function in libshlib.so:

```
void sharedStruct(struct data* d)
{
   d->number = calcSomething();
   d->message = doSomething();
}
```

I can send individual parameters (int and StringBuilder) and the library code runs and returns new values to the C# code that called it.

But how can I create a struct in C# that contains both int and string and send it to the unmanaged code (C library) which will populate the values to be used back in the C# code?

The C struct might be like this:

```
struct data
{
  int number;
  char* message;
};
```

Right now I'm trying to establish the best way to manipulate data in the C library for use in C#.  I am writing both pieces of code so I am flexible but right now I haven't been able to get it working.

Comment: Can you show us the `C` struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the struct to be populated by the C code, then you are probably looking for an `out` variable. Note that the mono runtime by default will use `free()` to deallocate any strings you pass in and you might have to take extra care with padding in structures (see the [StructLayout stuff in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx)). For strings, further problems can be had with character sets.

Sample code:

Managed.cs:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

struct Data
{
    public int number;
    public string message;
}

class Managed
{
    [DllImport("unmanaged")]
    extern static void Foo(out Data data);
    static void Main()
    {
        Data data;
        Foo(out data);
        Console.WriteLine("number = {0}, message = {1}", data.number, data.message);
    }
}
```

unmanaged.c:

```c
#include <string.h>

struct data
{
    int number;
    char* message;
};

void Foo(struct data* data)
{
    data->number = 42;
    data->message = strdup("Hello from unmanaged code!");
}
```

Test run:

```
$ mcs Managed.cs
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o libunmanaged.so unmanaged.c
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD mono Managed.exe
number = 42, message = Hello from unmanaged code!
```

Comment: Wow, could it be that easy??!! Thanks for posting all of the details. After many tries I had finally specified MarshallAs for both number and message, passed the struct as ref and found that I had to initialize message for it to work.  And I did also use:      [StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]